# Solving a linear PDE: $x^2 u_x - 2u_y - xu = x^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

For a homework problem in my course on PDEs, I'm to find the general solution to the following PDE:

$$x^2 u_x - 2u_y - xu = x^2$$

In addition, I'm to find the solution corresponding to the initial condition $u(x,0)=e^x$ and to graph some of the characteristic curves, but neither of those should really pose any trouble.

What *is* giving me trouble is finding the general solution. In essence, from what I've gathered is we are supposed to set up an equation

$$\frac{du}{dx} = u_x + u_y \frac{dy}{dx}$$

This equation should simplify somehow in general (drawing on the original PDE's partial derivatives) and lead to a simple ODE in which we solve for $y$.

However, here I get (noting that $dy/dx = -2/x^2$)

$$\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{x+u}{x}$$

which I can't really seem to do anything with. Notably, I was able to find something of that $x^2$ was just $0$ (the homogenous case), which would negate the $x$ in the numerator and make life so much easier, but I feel like that isn't how to go.

Is there something I'm missing? How exactly would one go about solving this?

---

For what it's worth, the solution is supposedly

$$u(x,y) = x \cdot f(y-2/x) + x \ln x$$

in the general case, from what I could look up online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give a comprehensive answer because I'm not sure what the whole problem is here. If you are just asking how to solve $$u' = \frac{x + u}{x}$$ then use an integrating factor (as I do below).

If we parameterise $u = u(x,y)$ with $t$ i.e $u(x,y) = u(x(t),y(t))$, then the chain rule says \begin{align} \frac{du}{dt} &= u_{x} \frac{dx}{dt} + u_{y} \frac{dy}{dt} \\ &= x^{2} u_{x} - 2 u_{y} \quad \text{(equating to PDE)} \\ &= xu + x^{2} \quad \text{(equating to PDE)} \end{align} Hence, the three ODEs you need to solve are \begin{align} x' &= x^{2} \\ y' &= -2 \\ u' &= xu + x^{2} \end{align} Eliminating $dt$ from each yields $$\frac{dx}{x^{2}} = \frac{dy}{-2} = \frac{du}{xu + x^{2}}$$ which is the parameterisation invariant form of the [Charpits method.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Characteristics_of_first-order_partial_differential_equation) Now we just need to solve any two combinations of these equations. Solving the first two \begin{align} dy &= \frac{-2 dx}{x^{2}} \\ \implies y &= \frac{2}{x} + c_{1} \end{align} Solving the first and third \begin{align} u' &= \frac{u}{x} + 1 \\ \implies u' - \frac{u}{x} &= 1 \\ \implies  \left( \frac{1}{x} u \right)' &= \frac{1}{x} \\ \implies \frac{1}{x} u &= \ln x + c_{2} \end{align} Now, for any differentiable function $\phi$, we have $\phi(c_{1}, c_{2}) = 0$ and hence \begin{align} \phi(c_{1}, c_{2}) &= \phi \left(y - \frac{2}{x}, \frac{1}{x} u - \ln x \right) \\ \implies \frac{1}{x} u - \ln x &= f \left(y - \frac{2}{x} \right) \quad \text{(equivalent to the form above)} \\ \implies u &= x \ln x + x f \left(y - \frac{2}{x} \right) \end{align}

Comment: It was the integrating factor method, I completely overlooked that. My bad, it's been a long time since I dealt with ODEs. I do appreciate the comprehensive response, though! ^_^

Comment: Ah ok, well at least you have the whole procedure now.